# Is there any way to create a value sorted map?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, search

I want to create map that instead sorting by default by key, its sorts by default by value.
For example if I have the following map;

```
map<string, pair<int,int> > map;
```

I dont want to have it sorted by the key (string), I want it sorted by default by the first int in the pair (value).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? (avoid XY problem) For enumeration, just sort the entries by value.

Comment: Then, by definition, the value is not a value anymore. The "value" by definition becomes the key, and the "key" by definition becomes the value.

Comment: Maybe you are seeking for a [bimap](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.bimap)?

Comment: Have you considered `std::map<string, std::map<int, int>>` instead?

Comment: You can provide a custom compare function to [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) if you need to.

Comment: Don't you want `std::map<int, std::pair<std::string, int>>` so ?

Comment: Jesper Jhul, how do I write the compare function by value?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Pretty sure after doing this the next question will be, "now how do i search by string?". I think the OP wants to iterate it by the value, but search it by string.

Comment: @Omair Iqbal "how do I write the compare function by value?" - you start by learning C++. Maybe pick up [a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and by reading the documentation I already linked to.

Comment: @Fantastic Mr Fox - possibly. We'll see.